# How do I install, learn and benefit maximally by using LaTeX

Tags: learning, tutorials

I am new to LaTeX, but learnt that it's the best document preparation as researchers. I have downloaded ProTeX, but I do not know anything about coding and programming, how do I ( I am a PhD mechanical engineering student ) start enjoying what the great researchers like you have been enjoying by optimally using it? What other program(s) do I need to download to maximally make the best of this document preparation? How do I collaborate with other researchers of different accent ( speaking a different language )? How can I import or export to MS word? Are there good or even better reference managers like EndNote on this platform? I would appreciate answers from intelligent professional / researchers. 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't have to know any coding/programming to use LaTeX. At least, very, *very* little.